# How to create a directory with yesterdays date in HDFS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hdfs, unix-timestamp

How can i create a directory with yesterday's date hadoop file system?

I tried the below command and it is creating with today's date

`hadoop fs -mkdir /user/"$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `date --date="13:00 yesterday"`

Comment: this one worked hadoop fs -mkdir /user/$(date --date="yesterday" +"%d-%m-%Y")

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and worked

hadoop fs -mkdir /user/$(date --date="yesterday" +"%d-%m-%Y")